# Re-arrange a data-frame: divide and line up according to the each divided group in R

Tags: r

I need to re-arrange my data frame. I tried "group_by" and "dcast" function but the that I want is quite different.
ColumnA is meal type like breakfast,lunch etc. ColumnC is glucose values for every 5min during meal. I want to arrange the data for each meal.That's mean is glucose values of meal 1 should be lined in first row. Glucose values of meal 2 shoul be line in second row. I couldn,t do that with 'dcast' function since I have several measures for meal 1 and column C should be categorized according to meal numbers and than lined up in same row.

My data is like that:

```
 A     B      C     D
 1   12:10   5.8    a
 1   12:15   7.1    a
 1   12:20   6.2    b
 2   15:05   4.2    b
 2   15:10   8.8    b
 3   20:35   5.9    a
 3   20:40   11.2   c
 3   20:45   7.8    c
```

I want to re-arrange the data frame like that:

```
 A          
 1    5.8   7.1   6.2 
 2    4.2   8.8
 3    5.9   11.2  7.8
```

How can solve it?
Many thanks

Comment: Explain! Don't drop 'before' and 'after' stuff. Show what you tried! I m voting to close

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.I thought that to explain can be more complicated. My english isn't well.ColumnA is meal type like breakfast,lunch etc. ColumnC is glucose values for every 5min during meal. I want to arrange the data for each meal.That's mean is glucose values of meal 1 should be lined in first row. Glucose values of meal 2 shoul be line in second row. I couldn,t do that with 'dcast' function since I have several measures for meal 1 and column C should be categorized according to meal numbers and than lined up in same row.If you need more explanation please let me know @Sotos

Comment: Is there someone to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `tidyverse` you can group by A, create a new column with rownumbers and spread, i.e.

**Base R**

```
d2 <- d1[c("A", "C")]
d2$rn <- ave(d2$A, d2$A, FUN = seq_along)
reshape(d2, idvar = "A", timevar = "rn", direction = "wide")

  A C.1  C.2 C.3
1 1 5.8  7.1 6.2
4 2 4.2  8.8  NA
6 3 5.9 11.2 7.8
```

**data.table**

```
library(data.table)

d1[, rn := rowid(A)]
dcast(d1, A ~ rn, value.var = "C")

   A   1    2   3
1: 1 5.8  7.1 6.2
2: 2 4.2  8.8  NA
3: 3 5.9 11.2 7.8
```

**Tidyverse**

```
library(tidyverse)

d1 %>% 
 select(A, C) %>% 
 group_by(A) %>% 
 mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
 pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = C)

# A tibble: 3 × 4
# Groups:   A [3]
      A   `1`   `2`   `3`
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   5.8   7.1   6.2
2     2   4.2   8.8  NA  
3     3   5.9  11.2   7.8
```